# Spring 4.3.5 annotation based configuration tomcat-8 404 in eclipse neon 2

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I have tried lot of time the same project to develop spring 4 based web app, but i am able to a project single time. I don't understand where i am making mistake. I have taken lot of references for my first Spring 4 annotation based first web application and i have followed each step by step. But all the time i failed. No i am here to understand where i am making mistake.

Please friend review and let me know the issue.

**Efforts**

Firstly i have create maven project and used `maven-archtypes-webapp` and specify group-ip, packages and so on.

Then, i have add dependencies and plugin, here is my `pom.xml` file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.org.spring4</groupId>
  <artifactId>FirstApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FirstApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>firstapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/</warSourceDirectory>
                <warName>firstapp</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then i have created annotation based configuration as mentioned on [http://websystique.com/](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/) this website. i have not created [it’s the preferred way] class, instead i have used first two classes.

here are both configuration classes:

```
AppConfig.java

package com.org.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.org.spring")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

and AppInitializer.java

```
package com.org.spring.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

after that i have created my controller as,

```
package com.org.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("name", "John Doe");

        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

then, i have created welcome.jsp file in WEB-INF/views directory as per my configuration.

When i tried to run this project on my tomcat 8 it gives me 404 error always. I don't know why i am getting this error.

Please friend help me.

Comment: Are you sure you indicated right packages to be scanned to Spring?

Comment: At what url are you getting the 404 error?

Comment: at ".../hello" url i am getting 404 error. I will get 404 error on "/" as i have no mapping for that.

Comment: After a research, i came to know that problem that i am thinking is configuration not loading. Is there something that i am missing in config file.

Answer (score -1):

change @Controller to @RestController and add @RequestMapping to your class in order to access to your api 
localhost:port/uri/apimapping/hello

Comment: He's not creating RESTful service so why would he change `@Controller` to `@RestController`?`@GetMapping` acts like a shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)` so no point in editing it either.

Comment: Is there anything that should i change ? I am not going to creating any restful service. I just want to create simple web application.